# android tessaract API to recognize non words

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I'm trying to recognize random chars in android with tess-two API .
I have a printed paper sheet with the string: "5XqaLB"
when i show to the camera parts of the string to recognize it, i get th following examples:

```
 original -> result
  "5XqaLB" -> "5anLB"  
  "XqaLB" -> "anLB"  
  "qaLB" -> "qaLB"  
  "5Xq" -> "5Xq"
```

I suppose this happens because tesseract tries to guess an word with the recognized chars. I searched a lot but can't find a solution. 
Anyone has ideas to avoid this tesseract replacements?

Already tried whitelist, blacklist, and confs like:

```
baseApi.setVariable("load_system_dawg", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("load_freq_dawg", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("load_punc_dawg", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("load_number_dawg", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("load_unambig_dawg", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("load_bigram_dawg", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("load_fixed_length_dawgs", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("segment_penalty_garbage", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("segment_penalty_dict_nonword", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("segment_penalty_dict_frequent_word", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("segment_penalty_dict_case_ok", "0");
baseApi.setVariable("segment_penalty_dict_case_bad", "0");
```

can anyone give any guess how to have tesseract recognize only plain chars?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve the similar problem I was having. In my case I was recognizing plate characters. Instead of using tesseract in the entire plate image I did a preprocess for separating the characters so I could use tesseract for each char separately. my config varibles:

```
final TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.init(TESSBASE_PATH, DEFAULT_DIC, TessBaseAPI.OEM_DEFAULT);
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ1234567890");

    baseApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_CHAR);
    baseApi.setVariable("load_system_dawg", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    baseApi.setVariable("load_freq_dawg", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    baseApi.setVariable("load_punc_dawg", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    baseApi.setVariable("load_number_dawg", TessBaseAPI.VAR_TRUE);
    baseApi.setVariable("load_unambig_dawg", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    baseApi.setVariable("load_bigram_dawg", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    baseApi.setVariable("load_fixed_length_dawgs", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    baseApi.setVariable("segment_penalty_garbage", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    baseApi.setVariable("segment_penalty_dict_nonword", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    baseApi.setVariable("segment_penalty_dict_frequent_word", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    baseApi.setVariable("segment_penalty_dict_case_ok", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    baseApi.setVariable("segment_penalty_dict_case_bad", TessBaseAPI.VAR_FALSE);
    return baseApi;
```

Comment: Sorry people!

I have a similar problem, but in the my case I use tess-two with open-cv to recognize plate number. 
I tried r3v3r53's method but no success, my next step would be compile traineddata files following tesseract tutorial( https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) but i'm accepting suggestions(I dont understand that tutorial very well so i'm not sure if it's gonna be helpful) 
for example: an image shows "FPD 0246" but the result is "FPJ 0245"


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp7zn.png

Comment: You really shouldn't use comments or the answerbox to ask a new question.